# Should a content site have both AMP and "normal" mobile versions?

Tags: seo, google, mobile, amp

We are trying to improve the Google functioning of some local news site(Custom built with PHP, no WordPress or anything like it).

Currently there are 3 versions for each page: desktop, mobile and AMP(all sit on the same domain).

**Both the desktop and mobile pages** have have rel="amphtml" pointing to the AMP version.
**Both The AMP and mobile versions** have rel="canonical" pointing to the desktop version.

Two questions:

1. Is there a need for a normal mobile page, when we have AMP? Can this create some kind of "redundancy"?
2. In the case of having a mobile page, should the AMP's "canonical" point to the desktop, or the mobile one?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't Google deprecating AMP?   Just focus on mobile and ditch AMP.

Comment: @stephenostermiller My impression of AMP was Google had an on-again/off-again relationship with it but it was currently on again?

Comment: I can't find it now, but I thought I just read an article saying that in May Google is no longer going to require AMP for Google News inclusion.  Instead they will accept any site that passes core vitals.  As far as I know, that is the only reason to use AMP.

Comment: Well requiring is one thing, using is another. AMP is just rapid.